# Power Query - How to call a function with optional parameter when that function is stored in a text file in an external folder?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I know that we can write and use Power Query functions with optional parameters like this:

```
(FolderPath as text, FileName as text, optional UpperLimitDate as text) =>
...
```

We call it like this inside a query:

Version 1: skipping the optional parameter

```
Source = FunctionName("C:\OneDrive\XC04 Locales Database\03 CSV Outputs\", "ar")
```

Version 2: including the optional parameter as empty (same as skipping)

```
Source = FunctionName("C:\OneDrive\XC04 Locales Database\03 CSV Outputs\", "ar", "")
```

Version 3: using the optional parameter with value

```
Source = FunctionName("C:\OneDrive\XC04 Locales Database\03 CSV Outputs\", "ar", "20200305")
```

I also know that we can store the function in a .txt file then write a pseudo-function connecting to the .txt file like this:

```
(FolderPath as text, FileName as text, UpperLimitDate as text) =>

let
GetFunction = Text.FromBinary(File.Contents(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NamedRangeStoringThePathToTheFolder"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]&"TextFileName.txt")),
EvaluateFunction = Expression.Evaluate(GetFunction, #shared),
EvaluateFunction2 = EvaluateFunction(FolderPath, FileName, UpperLimitDate)
in
EvaluateFunction2
```

My question is, how do we combine these two attributes?

1. Function with optional parameter
2. Function stored in a .txt file

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to remove the optional attribute from the function header **in the .txt file**:

```
(FolderPath as text, FileName as text, UpperLimitDate as nullable text) =>
```

It's probably a good idea to declare the optional parameter as **nullable text** everywhere to allow for null values.

In the pseudo-function header, make the third parameter optional:

```
(FolderPath as text, FileName as text, optional UpperLimitDate as nullable text) =>

let
GetFunction = Text.FromBinary(File.Contents(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NamedRangeStoringThePathToTheFolder"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]&"TextFileName.txt")),
EvaluateFunction = Expression.Evaluate(GetFunction, #shared),
EvaluateFunction2 = EvaluateFunction(FolderPath, FileName, UpperLimitDate)
in
EvaluateFunction2
```

Now try calling the pseudo function again. All of your 3 options should work.